# generators : object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, generator, differential-equations

I have this method : 
it's a solver stepper, I decide to develop it using generator for a question of elegance of the code. the problem here is that `u` is type: `np.array`

```
def step(f, t, u, dt):

    def f(ti,ui):
       return  np.array([function(ti,ui) for function in func])  
    um3 = u
    yield u + dt * f(t, u)

    um2 = u
    yield u + dt * f(t, u)

    um1 = u
    yield u + dt * f(t, u)

    while True:
        k1 = 55.0 * f(t, u)
        k2 = 59.0 * f(t - dt, um1)
        k3 = 37.0 * f(t - 2 * dt, um2)
        k4 = 9.0 * f(t - 2 * dt, um3)

        yield u + dt * (k1 - k2 + k3 - k4) / 24.0

        um3 = um2
        um2 = um1
        um1 = u
```

when I compile I got the error reported in the title.
How can I fix it ? is it possible have a generator that return an array ?

**EDIT** thanks for your interests ! here the full traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive.py", line 377, in <module>
    main()
  File "drive.py", line 224, in main
    f.write('%f %f \n' %(t, u[0] )) # u[0]) )
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
------------------------------------------------------------
```

@friederikk99 the code in which I call the generator is :

```
 with open('AdamsBashforth4_p1.dat', 'w') as f:
        while True:
            f.write('%f %f \n' %(t, u[0] )) # u[0]) )
            u = adamsmethods.AdamsBashforth._4th.step(func0,t,u,dt)
            t += dt
            if t > tf:
               break
```

ok I have change the line in :

```
f.write('%f %f \n' %(t, np.array(u)[0]))
```

but I got this strange message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive.py", line 378, in <module>
    main()
  File "drive.py", line 225, in main
    f.write('%f %f \n' %(t, np.array(u)[0])) # u[0]) )
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I've tried also like this :
`f.write('%f %f \n' %(t, list(u)[0]))` ... same error

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: Which code raises the exception? (i can't see anything being subscripted.) edit: i hate you for spelling my name wrong :3

Comment: Generators can return arrays for sure; but that not what you probably want. Also, generators can be converted into lists using `list(generator)`. IMPORTANT: The generator must yield finite values for it to work as expected.

Comment: `numpy.array` constructor won't work with a generator as you expect. but that is a different question